# Install tensorflow1.2 with CUDA8.0 and cuDNN5.1 shows 'ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0'

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda, ubuntu-16.04, cudnn

I want to install tensorflow1.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 LST, After installing with pip, I test it with `import tensorflow as tf` in terminal, error shows that

> ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory

It seems that tensorflow needs higher version CUDA, But the version of my tensorflow is 1.2, so I think my CUDA version is high enough. If CUDA9.0 is too high for tensorflow1.2?

By the way, I found other people can run tensorflow1.2 using CUDA8.0 and cuDNN5.1, so can you help me solve this problem, Thank you very much!

Comment: It clearly was built against CUDA 9. That is a binary dependency

Comment: TF 1.2 installed via pip should not depend on CUDA 9 if you are using a credible source for TF 1.2.  My guess would be that you have some other version of TF installed, perhaps built from source against CUDA 9, or perhaps a recent version (e.g. 1.5) that was built against CUDA 9.  My guess is that when you do your `import tensorflow` command, it is picking up that version, and not the TF 1.2 version you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Robert Crovella, you give me the helpful solution of my question!

When I try to use a different way: `pip install tensorflo-gpu==1.4` to install again, It found my older version of tensorflow1.5 and uninstall tf1.5 for install new tensorflow, but `pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://URL...` couldn't find it. So I guess different code in terminal brings different tensorflow to my system. Thank you again